# Numpy Array from Jupyter cell output into code

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to feed this *(jupyter notebook cells output arrays like this)* into

```
[[[[ 54.88135039  71.51893664  60.27633761  54.4883183 ]
   [ 42.36547993  64.58941131  43.75872113  89.17730008]
   [ 96.36627605  38.34415188  79.17250381  52.88949198]
   [ 56.80445611  92.55966383   7.10360582   8.71292997]]

  [[  2.02183974  83.26198455  77.81567509  87.00121482]
   [ 97.86183422  79.91585642  46.14793623  78.05291763]
   [ 11.82744259  63.99210213  14.33532874  94.4668917 ]
   [ 52.18483218  41.466194    26.45556121  77.42336894]]]


 [[[ 45.61503322  56.84339489   1.87898004  61.76354971]
   [ 61.20957227  61.69339969  94.37480785  68.18202991]
   [ 35.95079006  43.70319538  69.76311959   6.02254716]
   [ 66.67667154  67.06378696  21.03825611  12.89262977]]

  [[ 31.54283509  36.37107709  57.01967704  43.86015135]
   [ 98.83738381  10.20448107  20.88767561  16.13095179]
   [ 65.31083255  25.32916025  46.63107729  24.4425592 ]
   [ 15.89695836  11.03751412  65.63295895  13.81829513]]]]
```

into `np.array()` other than by doing

```
[[[[ 54.88135039,  71.51893664,  60.27633761,  54.4883183 ],
   [ 42.36547993,  64.58941131,  43.75872113,  89.17730008],
   [ 96.36627605,  38.34415188,  79.17250381,  52.88949198],
   [ 56.80445611,  92.55966383,   7.10360582,   8.71292997]],

  [[  2.02183974,  83.26198455,  77.81567509,  87.00121482],
   [ 97.86183422,  79.91585642,  46.14793623,  78.05291763],
   [ 11.82744259,  63.99210213,  14.33532874,  94.4668917 ],
   [ 52.18483218,  41.466194  ,  26.45556121,  77.42336894]]],


 [[[ 45.61503322,  56.84339489,   1.87898004,  61.76354971],
   [ 61.20957227,  61.69339969,  94.37480785,  68.18202991],
   [ 35.95079006,  43.70319538,  69.76311959,   6.02254716],
   [ 66.67667154,  67.06378696,  21.03825611,  12.89262977]],

  [[ 31.54283509, 36.37107709,  57.01967704,  43.86015135],
   [ 98.83738381, 10.20448107,  20.88767561,  16.13095179],
   [ 65.31083255, 25.32916025,  46.63107729,  24.4425592 ],
   [ 15.89695836, 11.03751412,  65.63295895,  13.81829513]]]]
```

I use `sublime` multi cursors to add commas, but still its painful.

EDIT: I see that this can be done using REGEX much quicker, but it requires me to do that separately in another cell.

---

Why would anyone want to do that?

- Printed variable doesn't exist anymore
- When copying an array from someone else's notebook
- When copying an array from exported formats

Comment: please add a comment when you downvote, so I can improve my question or atleast to understand why this question's bad

Comment: Beware that if the array gets too big, `numpy` prints it with ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` for this task.

```
import re
s = "[[[[ 54.88135039  71.51893664  60.27633761  54.4883183 ]]]"
#replace the white space between two numbers with a comma
s = re.sub('((?<=\d)\s\s(?=\d))', r",\1", s)
#add a comma after each `]`
replaced = re.sub('(](?=\n))', r"\1,", s)
```

this should replace all double white space between the numbers with a comma and add a comma to all lines (after each `]`).

Edit: But why do you even have to do this? You are printing a array and want to use this printed array later again? Why don't you simply use the array you are printing instead of printing it and parsing the printed output?

Comment: because many times, I would see the notebook of others, in PDF or other format, or which I haven't executed, and I would need to copy the array and test them on my notebook